# How to hide an automationelement?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, winapi, ui-automation

I've been working for a few days on this and would like if nothing more some confirmation or a few hints as to where to go next on this task.
I've been tasked with hiding certain notifications within Chrome that Chrome doesn't provide a native option to hide - even in kiosk or incognito mode. The approach I have been using is Microsoft's Automation API to get access to these objects, which is relatively easy because I can find them by classname or by some of the text contained within the object - which is necessary. The challenge now is that I need to hide the element and/or it's container without closing Chrome :)

Easy enough to get the main handle to Chrome:

```
 private IntPtr GetChromeHandle()
        {
            IntPtr chWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
            Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
            foreach (Process chrome in procsChrome)
            {
                // the chrome process must have a window
                if (chrome.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    chWnd = chrome.MainWindowHandle;
                }
            }
            return chWnd;
        }
```

I can get one of these elements pretty easily from there by doing the following:

```
PropertyCondition pcFullScreen = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "F11", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase);
            AutomationElement fsTest = chromeWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, pcFullScreen);
```

The challenge here is how to close that element or navigate to a high level that I can close it?

Alternate approach tried looks like this:

```
PropertyCondition pcTest = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Intermediate D3D Window");
            AutomationElement newTestElm = chromeWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, pcTest);
```

Problem here is that while I can "hide/close" by using the handle of the class, I can't seem to narrow it down to an instance of the class that contains the text I'm looking for. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Per a comment, tried to access via WindowPattern and get "null" based on this code:

```
private WindowPattern GetWindowPattern(AutomationElement targetControl)
    {
        WindowPattern windowPattern = null;

        try
        {
            windowPattern =
                targetControl.GetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern)
                as WindowPattern;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            // object doesn't support the WindowPattern control pattern
            return null;
        }
        // Make sure the element is usable.
        if (false == windowPattern.WaitForInputIdle(10000))
        {
            // Object not responding in a timely manner
            return null;
        }
        return windowPattern;
    }
```

Comment: Wait for the notification to show up, then use Inspect.exe to use the mouse to find the notification and see where it is in the automation tree?

Comment: Fair point, but even then, how can I close/hide it? So far using PInvoke functions to attempt to close the closest handle have resulted in hiding the entire Chrome window except for the title bar (which is a bit humorous)

Comment: Inspect.exe is not Spy++. Inspect.exe is specifically for looking at UI Automation trees, and you would not get handles to close from it.

Comment: Right - but you can roll up to view the NativeWindowHandle property and at least figure out the container. The challenge seems to be that I need to simply hide the control found in the automationtree and forget trying handles

Comment: You could try seeing if the Automation element implements WindowPattern; [the discussion of balloon tips here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752035(v=vs.110).aspx) makes me think that other notification boxes could also implement that provider, maybe?

Comment: Finding out what patterns are supported on the element in question is critical.   In particular, you should not rely on elements (or containers) having NativeWindowHandles.

Comment: I did just try seeing if I could use a WindowPattern to close these particular elements with no success. Will post code shortly when I'm fairly certain it's not something obvious. Based on example from MS - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.close(v=vs.110).aspx Thanks for the responses so far!

Comment: Added code above with attempt at WindowPattern

Comment: Chrome used not to be very UI automation friendly, unfortunately. Maybe that has changed.

Comment: Simon is right. You have to run Chrome with "--force-renderer-accessibility" cmd flag to get full control. But if you don't control the moment of Chrome start-up, this is not the option.